# C# Mongodb. Sum field for all documents

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to calculate total for all document in the collection. For example, I have the following three documents:

```
_id: 1,
clientId: 1,
cash: 500

_id: 2,
clientId: 1,
cash: 100

_id: 3,
clientId: 2,
cash: 200
```

So, I want to sum `cash` field for the specific `clientId`. For the client 1 I want to get `600`, for the client 2 I wanto get `200`. It's my first usage of aggregation frameworkd in MongoDB. I checked documentation and the other questions from SO, but can't figure out, why I have to use `group` clause. Why do I need it, if just want to sum. I event tried to use `Group` but can't get it compile:

```
_collection.Aggregate().Match(t=>t.ClientId == 1).Group(null, g => new
            {
                Total = g.Sum(o => o.Cash)
            });
```

> No overload for method 'Group' takes 2 arguments

PS. I don't want to use `BsonDocument` and such thing like `$sum` keywords. I want to make it in more C# way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

is this ok?

```
var Total = _collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ClientId == 2).Sum(x => x.Cash);
```

EDIT: aggregate is overkill here but it would go maybe like this:

```
var x = MongoCollection.Aggregate()
                    .Group(
                            doc => doc.clientId,
                            group => new
                            {
                                clientId = group.Key,
                                Total = group.Sum(y => y.sum)
                            }
                    ).ToList().FirstOrDefault(c => c.clientId == 2).Total;
```

aggregation is executed in Db until it goes toList()

Comment: Generally, yes, but I want to see how I can accomplish this task via aggregation framework. BTW, the code that you provided, will it be executed in a database or in memory?

Comment: I apologize for using different variable names, but I think you get the idea. I think @Skami is right about first solution being executed in db.

Comment: @BOR4. yeah, I managed to fix it by mysel and my code is the same. Insdead of ToList()... I tried to do projection with `Project`, but got exception, but it's a different story. Thanks.

Comment: @user348173 any time pal, glad I could help.

Comment: You can also filter on the aggregate as a first step with Match, so that you have only one result.

The first option executes in memory the sum, which is not ideal.